# Add class to active tab && Add class inActive to inactive tab

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have three "li" tabs and one showTab "div".

I want that the clicked tab to show in showTab and this is working fine, but I also want to add class active to the clicked tab, and add inActive class to other tabs (siblings) that are not clicked.

One tab should have always active class.

I'm totally new to Javascript so excuse me for my ignorance.

Here is the link to my code:
[code](https://codepen.io/bishuddev/pen/qgQKxK)

I have tried this in jQuery before and what I'm trying to achieve now is similarly to this:

```
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $(this).siblings('.tabs').removeClass('active');
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="tab-container">
  <div class="showtab active">
    <img class='showtabimg' src="" alt="showtabimg">
  </div>
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab tab1 ">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550364387-ffbad4f8e9b2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" alt="foto1" class='img '>
    </li>
    <li class="tab tab2 ">
     <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550368759-0fdb22fe8020?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" alt="foto2" class='img'>
    </li>
    <li class="tab tab3 ">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550371554-387863e7bd38?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" alt="foto3" class='img'>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul li{
  list-style: none;
}
.showtab{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.showtab img{
  width: 100%;
}
.tabs{
  display: flex;
}
.tabs li{
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;

}
.tabs li img{
  width: 100%;
}

.active{
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid red !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.inActive{
  color: blue;
   border: 1px solid blue;
  opacity: .3;
}
```

**JS**

```
var tabs = document.querySelector('.tabs');
var tab = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');
var showTab = document.querySelector('.showtab');
var img = document.querySelector('.showtabimg');

tab.forEach(thumbNail => {
  thumbNail.addEventListener('click',function(item){
    var content = item.target.getAttribute("src");

    this.classList.toggle('active')

    img.setAttribute('src', content);


  } );
});
```

Comment: Well, logically, you can simply add the `inActive` class and remove the `active` to all of `tab`, then add the `active` class and remove the `inActive` class for the clicked element. You might find it easier to simply style them by default as inactive, then you can just toggle the active class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all class active then toggle class - javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50075497/remove-all-class-active-then-toggle-class-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to delete the classes of items that are outside of clicked

Delete all active elements of all elements before all other operations

```
tab.forEach(thumbNail => {
  thumbNail.addEventListener('click',function(item){
    // delete all active or normal elements active class
    tab.forEach(i => i.classList.remove('active'))

    var content = item.target.getAttribute("src");

    this.classList.toggle('active')

    img.setAttribute('src', content);
  } );
});
```

Comment: thank you Minan, this solved my problem.
Accepted as answer.